# C getline function prevents displacement with arrow keys

Tags: c, linux, input

I'm using the function `getline()` in a C program to get an input line from the user as follows:

```
char *buff = NULL;
size_t input_size = 0;
while (1) {
  printf("Enter a line: ");
  if (getline(&buff, &input_size, stdin) == -1) {
    printError();
    free(buff);
    continue;
  }
  //Rest of code...      
}
```

The problem is, when the user writes something and wants to move the cursor to another line location with the arrow keys, the cursor doesn't move as in a standard console input. Instead, it prints on the input buffer the corresponding arrow character codes:

```
line^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[D
```

Looking for a solution, I found libraries to replace `getline()` and event-oriented solutions. But I wonder if there exists some standard C function equivalent to `getline()` or another solution that doesn't depend on external libraries.

Comment: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: @david-ranieri Why is it necessary to use external libraries? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: RE: `is it necessary to use external libraries` - unfortunately yes, the standard functions work on a buffer without taking into account any particularity of the terminal, another option is to use `termios.h` in non-canonical mode, or maybe `ncurses`, but those headers are not part of the standard either.

Comment: And of course, at very low cost, you can open a pipe with Python (It seems that you are an expert in this field :), and take advantage of its simplicity, c is a pain in the *ss for such things.

Comment: If one existed, everyone would be using it and you would never see any `^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[D`.

Comment: On linux try screen -t xterm

Comment: @gulpr how does assigning a name or a title to a newly created screen helps in this question?

Comment: @DavidRanieri typo screen -T xterm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I wonder if there exists some standard C function equivalent to `getline()` or another solution that doesn't depend on external libraries.

The C standard does not provide such a facility.